# Accent and ñ in A-frame

Tags: fonts, aframe

How can a write accents or ñ in A-frame? When i write ñ or accents the the character disappears

```
<a-entity text="value:áT&aacute;ílde y e'ñ'; color:#FFFFFF; 
   shader: msdf; font:fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.json;" 
   scale="15 15 15" position="6.7 1 -2"></a-entity>
```

I found a lot of fonts in https://github.com/soimy/msdf-bmfont-xml but none work with accents or `ñ`.

I try to make a font with accents but I can't. I don't quite understand this article https://levelup.gitconnected.com/msdf-font-rendering-in-webgl-91ce192d2bec